# How to get all tunes downloaded to my iPhone from the cloud?

Tags: ios, icloud, music

I have tunes that show on iCloud but I can't get them on my iPhone. How do I restore these? These represent about half of my saved music. When I backup I only get the songs that are currently on my iPhone. This happened when I upgraded to the iPhone 6 from the iPhone 5.

Comment: Backup will never backup anything that can be retrieved from another source (for example, app bundles, purchased movies, etc). When you say you "can't get them" back onto your phone, can you clarify what you mean? Do they show in Music with the iCloud icon next to them, but can't be downloaded?

Answer (score 1):

If your songs are stored in icloud there are two ways you can able to restore.

1. Restore Music from iCloud with iTunes
2. Restore Music from iCloud Directly on Your Device.

Try using AnyTrans .. It's the best option to manage your iCloud backups. Besides this, it also supports transfer iOS contents to anywhere you like.